# How to Access an Object's Variables/Methods using Another Variable

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

Suppose that I have a `struct Node` which contains `x` and `y` and I would like to create a vector of these `Node`s.

```
struct Node {
    int x;
    int y;
    Node(int x, int y);
};

vector<Node *> nodes;
```

I would like to write various functions that work either on `x` or `y`. For example, I want to write a `sort` function that sorts the nodes vector by `x` coordinates and another one which sorts based on `y`.

It is definitely a better idea to write a single function that implements both sort_by_x and sort_by_y. I was thinking of writing a function which takes a `bool` like `isX` and performs the sorting accordingly. However, I would like to avoid writing the same code twice (once for x and once for y). I want to write a single piece of code that performs the corresponding sorting. I tried to implement this using the following code, but it is not valid in C++ (because it expects `c` to be one of the variables in `Node`).

```
void mySort(vector<Node *> &nodes, bool isX) {
    char c;
    if (isX) {
        c = 'x';
    }
    else {
        c = 'y';
    }

    // some code
    nodes[i]->c // if c == 'x', x will be used, otherwise  y.
}
```

Would you please let me a workaround to rewrite the above code or some other way of implementing the same functionalities based on different variables?

Comment: If you want a vector of `Node`s, do that: `std::vector<Node>`. Vectors of pointers are not generally so fun. As for sorting, there's already a `std::sort` function that you can pass a comparator for `x` or `y` into. Hopefully, you'll soon be able to simply pass `&Node::x` or `&Node::y` instead of wrapping it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. sorting is just a simple example. I would like to implement some other functions that are not available in STL.

Comment: You can use `std::sort` as an example and design yours the same way. Better yet, you can use something similar to `std::invoke` to make that pointer to member option work and provide a version that takes a projection function. Those two things are useful across the board.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not quite familiar with these concepts, but I'll take a look.

Comment: BTW, why do you think a vector of pointers is not fun? :)

Comment: Pointers don't typically Just Work™ the same way normal objects do. You have to dereference them and handle null checks while you do it. Fortunately, `std::invoke` includes support for pointers when given something like `&Node::x`. That is, `std::invoke(&Node::x, nodePtr)` will produce `(*nodePtr).*&Node::x`. In general, however, things tend to accept references instead of pointers. There's no extra syntax involved in using a reference. With a container of raw pointers, it can also get disastrous if those pointers own a resource and you have to iterate through to clean them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *pointer to member* here:

```
int Node::*m;
if (isX) {
    m = &Node::x;
}
else {
    m = &Node::y;
}

// some code
nodes[i]->*m
```

The syntax is fairly ugly, but it does exactly what you're trying to do. If you have C++11 available an alternative would be to write simple lambda functions to return `x` or `y` and store them in a `std::function`; this is slightly less efficient, but less ugly and more general.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've heard about lambda functions, but never used them before. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort` allows a comparator to be passed in as a third argument. You can change the behavior of the sort by using a different comparator for the `x` case and the `y` case.

```
std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
          [](const Node *a, const Node *b) -> bool {
              return a->x < b->x;
          });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sorting is just a simple example. I would like to implement some other functions that are not available in STL. By the way, this is a good hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write your own function to do the sorting. The standard library already has a generic [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function. You can use it like this:

```
auto x_comparator = [](auto a, auto b) { return a->x < b->x; }
auto y_comparator = [](auto a, auto b) { return a->y < b->y; }

std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), x_comparator); // sort by x
std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), y_comparator); // sort by y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sorting is just a simple example. I would like to implement some other functions that are not available in STL. By the way, this is a good hint. Thanks.